# String iterators incompatible ERROR when I convert string to vector<byte>

Tags: c++, vector

I have Const variable :

```
#define     ERROR_ME        std::string("Error Message")
```

in the function, I want return std::vector
so, I write this:

```
return std::vector<byte>(ERROR_ME.begin(), ERROR_ME.end()); // this have error
```

can you help me?

Comment: Please don't use `#define` to declare constants.  If you want a constant use `const datatype = something;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't have a "Const [sic] variable", you have a symbolic constant that is replaced in the source before the compiler proper gets a chance to read it.

The code the compiler will see is not

```
return std::vector<byte>(ERROR_ME.begin(), ERROR_ME.end());
```

but instead

```
return std::vector<byte>(std::string("Error Message").begin(), std::string("Error Message").end());
```

That is, you get the `begin` and `end` iterators from two different and unrelated objects. Comparing or other interacting of unrelated iterators leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If you want a true constant then use e.g.

```
std::string const ERROR_ME = "Error Message";
```

Comment: this return std::vector<byte>(std::string("Error Message").begin(), std::string("Error Message").end()); not work, but when i use const variable it's ok(std::string const ERROR_ME = "Error Message";), tanx